# How to get the raw data of a 1-D Barcode Image?

Tags: c#, barcode, gs1-128, gs1-ai-syntax

I am generating 1D Barcodes for USPS's EAN-128.  But I don't have a scanner to check the end result.

Is there a free tool where I can use to check the Raw Data of the barcode?  E.g. with the Start, FNC1, End, Mod103 checksum, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JustScanIt](https://aka.ms/justscanit/) is a free app to download and use instantly, where you can also 1) set verbosity for greater detail, 2) use clipboard to paste the decoded data in other docs, and 3) find examples in the help section for using the built-in commercial grade barcode scanning API found in Windows (lots of symbologies included and added as new versions of Windows are released).

More than most, it also provides control of advanced camera focus capabilities for higher performing read rates.

Answer (score 3):

https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx will give some fairly detailed information on a decoded barcode.  For example, this barcode is a GS1 code128 that uses an FNC1 for the leading code word:

[image: (01)95012345678903(3103)000123]

The xzing response shows the following:

```
Raw text    
01950123456789033103000123
Raw bytes   
69 66 01 5f 01 17 2d 43   59 03 1f 03 00 01 17 5b
6a 
Barcode format  CODE_128
Parsed Result Type  TEXT
Parsed Result   
01950123456789033103000123
```

You can see in the raw result the 0x69 start code word, 0x66 FNC1 code word, 0x5b check sum and 0x6a stop code word.